# $.parseXML add xmlns to inner <p> tag

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt

I have follwing xml stirng.

```
var xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <abc xmlns="mynamespaceURI" >
  <item><object><p><min><objectB></objectB></min></object></item>
  </abc>"
```

when I parse this with $.parseXML(xml) it add
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
to inner 
    "p" 
tag

But I am converting this to HTML using XSL so if namespaces is added to inner tag it cannot convert inner XML tag to corresponding HTML tag mentioned in my XSL file. So is there where to parseXML without addin xmlns tag to inner tags

Comment: That snippet does not even parse as XML as the closing `</p>` missing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem at https://jsfiddle.net/0v3yrrrv/2/.

Comment: Only if I intentionally insert an XHTML element in the XML snippet, as in https://jsfiddle.net/0v3yrrrv/3/, the parsed document also contains one.

Comment: provide a proper schema then

Comment: @MartinHonnen it was my mistake that I miss the closing </p>.  But still after parse it get xmlns tag inside p tag. And I think as your jsfiddle you have reproduce the problem as you are getting the result "Found 1 XHTML element(s)." I need my end result as "Found 0 XHTML element(s)." as in your fiddle.

Comment: Which browser and which version of JQuery are you using? https://jsfiddle.net/0v3yrrrv/2/ shows `Found 0 XHTML element(s).` for me with IE 11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox on Windows 10. The second link to the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/0v3yrrrv/3/) is, as said, of course meant to test parsing of an XHTML element. How about using the code snippet feature here on Stackoverflow to insert directly in your question a minimal but complete snippet allowing us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I used regex to find and remove the xmlns tag and it worked.